# Windows 10 Home Anniversary update: long path fix not working?

Tags: windows-10

I read on a few websites the Windows 10 Home Anniversary update fixed the bug that prevented long path names over 260 characters. I am running version 1511 (Build 10586) but am still having an issue with the long file and path names after the update. Is there a way to allow the long paths and file names after the update?

I've tried using regedit.exe and creating a LongPathsEnabled set to 1. After restarting this had no effect for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read on a few websites the Windows 10 Home Anniversary update fixed the bug that prevented long path names over 260 characters

The 260 character limit that windows explorer had, wasn't a bug, it was 260 characters on purpose.

> I am running version 1511 (Build 10586) but am still having an issue with the long file and path names after the update.

If you are running Version 1511, the features upgrade, has not been applied to your system.  You have to upgrade to Version 1607 in order to recieve the feature upgrade.  The limit is still 260, since your using Windows 10 Version 1511, where the limit is still 260 characters.

Comment: I asked another question about my issue on this here: http://superuser.com/questions/1114572/windows-10-ver-1607-file-explorer-long-paths-not-working

It turns out the long paths don't work in File Explorer as of the 1607 update. The long paths may work for other programs.