# Windows 10 ver 1607: File Explorer long paths not working?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I updated to the Windows 10 home anniversary edition version 1607 and set LongPathsEnabled to 1 with regedit.exe but the File Explorer doesn't seem to work with long paths still. If you select a long path file and try to rename it, no option will be available. I restarted the computer after making the changes and update.

Is there any way to enable renaming in the File Explorer in the new updated version? Did I miss a step somewhere?

Comment: ok, I checked the exe and it doesn't include the entry in the manifest, so the Explorer is not long path aware

Comment: Thanks for checking magicandre1981! Is there any way to fix this error? Sorry I don't really understand too much of what is happening behind the scenes to make long files work or not.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've asked Microsoft employee [Gov Maharaj](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show) and the feature is not ready to be enabled for Windows Explorer. So you still have the issue with Explorer. You have to wait until Microsoft enables it for Explorer or use a 3rd party file management tool which is compatible with the long paths and has the setting

```
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
  <windowsSettings>
    <longPathAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">true</longPathAware>
  </windowsSettings>
</application>
```

set in its manifest file.

Comment: `robocopy` ships for free with Windows, and respects the long paths setting

Comment: @Coruscate5 Technically robocopy does not respect the long paths setting; it supports long paths regardless of the setting, and has done so long before Windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

**Fixed It**
You could use [One Commander](http://onecommander.com/download.html), a Windows Explorer like app, to copy files with long absolute paths.
I tried it on my Win 10 when an upgrade to version 1607 too did not fix the long file name issue.

I was able to successfully copy the files.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I managed to create a file/rename a file that exceeded the 260 length limit without any issues.