# Windows 10 "Enable NTFS long paths policy" option missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs, filenames, windows-10-v1607

For some time, Microsoft has supported an option to remove the limit of 260 symbols for NTFS file name length.

The web is full of articles, describing what should be done.

1. Hit the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type `gpedit.msc` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Navigate to `Local Computer Policy` > `Computer Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `System` > `Filesystem` > `NTFS`.
3. Double click the `Enable NTFS long paths` option and enable it.

However, I don't have such option. Please see the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]

Am I missing some Windows update, or is it something else?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The value has moved from `NTFS` directly into `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem` in the RTM version of the Version 1607.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This path: `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem` is missing for me. I have win 10 home premium but installed gpedit using http://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i

Comment: @gyozokudor - You can easily add the group policy editor to [Windows 10 Home](http://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i).

Comment: @Ramhound I've added it, my main problem is that the setting is missing.

Comment: @gyozokudor - Which is the reason, any group policy, has a corresponding registry key assosicated with it.  Of course I will point out, that Windows Explorer, does not yet support the longer path names.

Comment: It's worth noting that most programs (Windows Explorer included) don't yet recognize the long file paths feature yet - `robocopy` is one of the few built-in exceptions that will copy directory files with the new feature

Comment: @Coruscate5 yes, as I already posted in a 2nd question: http://superuser.com/a/1114683/174557

Comment: As @Coruscate5 said Windows Explorer and Visual Studio still imposes the 260 chars rule. However, PowerShell and Visual Studio Code seem to understand the longer file / directory path.

Comment: I just tried this `Enable Win32 long paths` Local Group Policy on my Win 10 machine after finding your answer here. Unfortunately, I still get this error when trying to upload an image to Facebook by pasting (as a filename) a URL of an image on the web: "The path is too long. Try a shorter name."

Comment: @Ryan this settings doesn't fix the issue. It is 1 part. The Apps must have the entry [longPathAware in its manifest](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/)

Comment: @magicandre1981 If you happen to know how to add it to Chrome's manifest, I have a question here: https://superuser.com/questions/1504123/use-url-of-an-image-in-windows-10-file-upload-form?noredirect=1&lq=1 Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan configure Windows to [prefer external manifest](https://www.unixgr.com/enable-external-manifest-control-on-windows-10/), export the chrome manifest with a ResourceHacker and add the longPathAware entry to the manifest file named **chrome.exe.manifest**

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you!

Comment: With Windows 10 1809 the entry is neither in `Filesystem` nor in `Filesystem\NTFS`. Was this removed from the Local Group Policies?

Comment: @riQQ I still see it in Win10 2004, so I guess you overlook it.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I double checked. I'm pretty sure it's not there. Can this be hidden in Windows 10 Enterprise?

Comment: I checked a 1809 VM and I can see the entry

Comment: @riQQ have you checked the 1809 again?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes, I checked multiple times. I don't know the Enterprise customization options, but I can imagine that my company removed some of these options if that is possible. Setting long path via registry works until it's overwritten, probably by domain GPOs.

Comment: @riQQ ok, this is possible, I checked my 1809 Pro VM

Answer (score 25):

Modify applicable registry settings as listed in the below answers to potentially help resolve.

### Know your Build Version

You can run `WINVER` to see what build your **Windows 10** is but from what I gather with a little reading, the enabling of **NTFS long paths** is available as of **Build 14352** and later, so check to see if your build release is older than that for an explanation why it's not an option from **Group Policy** otherwise.

[image]

---

### Update - Newer Version Builds

<sup>***WARNING:** Before working in the Windows Registry, it is always a good idea to back it up first, so that you have the option of restoration, should something go wrong. [This article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/backup-and-restore-registry-windows) shows the different ways to back up and restore the Windows Registry or its Hives.*</sup>

It seems that the registry locations with some of the latest Windows 10 Anniversary updates have changed a bit to enable the Long Paths to help overcome the Windows API file paths and names that exceed a 255-260 character limit for such programs in Windows that can utilize this once enabled.

### Registry Import Enabling Long Paths

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"LongPathsEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

---

### Optional Registry Value

The below registry key value changed when the option was made with the **Local Group Policy** editor to **enable** `Enable Win32 long paths` but the `<SID>` portions will likely be different per account defined with a profile, etc. on the local Windows 10 machine s plug those values in accordingly per what you see when you look there with regedit.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-[<SID>-<SID>-<SID>]-1001\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy Objects\{B0D05113-7B6B-4D69-81E2-8E8836775C9C}Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"LongPathsEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

[image]

**<sup>NOTE:</sup>** *<sup>Once you have these imported, you'll want to reboot to ensure the changes become effective just in case. It has been reported that these settings and even Group Policy settings that change these values and others [do NOT always work with File Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/1114572/windows-10-ver-1607-file-explorer-long-paths-not-working?rq=1) or all Windows programs as those have to be coded to handle this explicitly from what I gather so this is not a 100% for sure will fix all issues but this is Microsoft's step forward moving to resolve this limitation.</sup>*

---

### Previous Version Builds

**<sup>Warning:</sup>** *<sup>These below settings may not work for all builds of Windows 10 so you will need to backup, check, test, etc. but see the options above if you've not already.</sup>*

> ### Using the Registry instead at HKLM Level
>
> 1. Hit the Windows key, type **regedit** and press **Enter**
> 2. Go to the following Registry key:
>    **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Policies`**
> 3. On the right side, *create a new 32-bit DWORD* value named **LongPathsEnabled**. Set its value data to **1**.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Restart Windows 10
>
> <sub>[source](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-enable-ntfs-long-paths-in-windows-10/)</sub>

---

> ### Using the Registry instead at HKCU Level
>
> 1. Hit the Windows key, type **regedit** and press **Enter**.
> 2. Navigate to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group
>    Policy Objects{48981759-12F2-42A6-A048-028B3973495F}
>    Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Policies
> 3. Select the **LongPathsEnabled** key, or create it as a DWORD (32-bit)
>    value if it does not exist.
> 4. Set the value to **1** and close the Registry Editor.
>
> <sub>[source](http://betanews.com/2016/05/29/long-paths-windows-10/)</sub>

Comment: I have `Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.105)` and i still do not have the option there, either in the poilicy editor or in regedit. @magicandre1981 has the correct solution

Comment: For HKCU I don't have such a folder/key. Do I need one big folder named `Group Policy Objects{48981759-12F2-42A6-A048-028B3973495F} Machine` or did you just forget the slashes, something like this? `Group Policy Objects\{48981759-12F2-42A6-A048-028B3973495F}\Machine`

Comment: Winver says the following: Version: 1607 (OS Build: 14393.105)

Comment: [Windows 10 ver 1607: File Explorer long paths not working?](http://superuser.com/questions/1114572/windows-10-ver-1607-file-explorer-long-paths-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: See the section in the answer ***Registry Import Enabling Long Paths*** for the registry settings that need applied for the newer versions of **Windows 10** where using the `gpedit.msc` method is not available or if you just want to use that method instead of the Group Policy. The older version registry is at the bottom of the answer with applicable detail and the newer is up top but if you read it thru, it should be clear and not overly complicated.

Comment: Will it become `On` by default in the future?

Comment: You only have to change the value in CurrentControlSet (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291519/how-does-currentcontrolset-differ-from-controlset001-and-controlset002)

Comment: I can't find a Microsoft source either. I can only anecdotally confirm, that it works only changing `CurrentControlSet` on Windows 10 Enterprise 1809.

Comment: You don't need to modify both `CurrentControlSet` and `ControlSet001`, since the former one is just a link to either `ControlSet001`, `ControlSet002`, or `ControlSet003`, etc. Generally the node with the largest number suffix is currently using.