# Windows 8.1 “Enable NTFS long paths policy” option missing

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, ntfs

Tring to enable long path in windows 8.1 but unable to find the option available

have a look

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qka6B.png)

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm4gA.png]

Managed to locate this screen by following the link [Windows 10 "Enable NTFS long paths policy" option missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing)

Please assist