# Use URL of an image in Windows 10 file upload form

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

If there is a form that allows uploading an image, I often want to provide a URL of an image on the web instead of an image on my machine.

I'd love NOT to need to download the image to my machine first (just to then upload the image in the form, and then go delete the image from my machine).

However, URLs for images are often 700+ characters.

[image]

Windows 10 always then throws this error:

[image]

> "The path is too long. Try a shorter name."

I already tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing#comment2272403_1119980) `Enable Win32 long paths` Local Group Policy on my Win 10 machine. Unfortunately, I still get this error when trying to upload an image to Facebook by pasting (as a filename) a URL of an image on the web.

**How can I skip the step of downloading an image to my machine if I want to upload that image?**

Comment: try using a url shortener>>>>>https://bitly.com/

Comment: @Moab That's similarly adding an extra step (and might be even more inconvenient than what I'm already doing). Thanks for the thought though.