# How to start a program on a path longer than 260 characters on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

I am working on a long path support for an application. The problem is, I cannot even start the program: when I place it on a path longer than 260 characters, I get this pop-up error when starting it:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000106). Click OK to close the application.

I have enabled long path support as [described here](https://superuser.com/q/1119883/194976) and I can confirm that at least some programs can open files on paths over the limit. But opening files is not enough, I need to actually start the program at such long path. How can I do that?