# Why can't windows explorer delete files with long paths and why can 7-zip do it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, path

I don't know if this is the right place to ask such a question. For me at least it is really strange that Microsoft's own windows explorer cannot delete files with long paths while 7-zip file manager can. Why can't Microsoft fix his own file browser? I have Windows 10 Home Premium.

Edit:
My question is different from [Windows 10 "Enable NTFS long paths policy" option missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1119883) because in my case there is no setting when I run gpedit.
[image]

Edit2:
Although this seems to answer my question or at least give an explanation why it's not working: [Windows 10 ver 1607: File Explorer long paths not working?](https://superuser.com/questions/1114572/windows-10-ver-1607-file-explorer-long-paths-not-working?rq=1)

Comment: Look here for an explanation https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/4/Troubleshooting/Windows_File_Paths_Longer_Than_255_Characters and look here if you're on Windows 10  for some workaround settings now -- both answers from this post: http://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-otpion-missing/1119948#1119948

Comment: [Windows 10 ver 1607: File Explorer long paths not working?](http://superuser.com/questions/1114572/windows-10-ver-1607-file-explorer-long-paths-not-working?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change windows LongPathsEnabled policy.
Open registry editor(regedit) with admin privileges and navigate to following path:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem

and search for LongPathsEnabled key. if the key exists, right click on it and select edit. Then change its value from 0 to 1.

if the file is not exist, then create it: right click on FileSystem directory and select New > DWORD|(32 bit).
Rename the key to LongPathsEnabled and change its value from 0 to 1.
close the regedit and restart windows.

long path policy will deactivate and you shall not receive the long path message anymore.
I've tested this on Windows 10 and worked.

Comment: I've not tested this solution on windows 7, but you try it.

Comment: I have already added this but I am unable to delete files with long paths. Does this work on Win 10 Home Premium? I have also added registry keys mentioned here: http://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-otpion-missing and here http://betanews.com/2016/05/29/long-paths-windows-10. I don't have group policy editor because I'm using Home premium, so I can only edit the registry.

Comment: @S.VahidHosseini `LongPathsEnabled` does not apply to Windows Explorer at this time.

Comment: @gyozokudor - You can easily add the group policy editor to [Windows 10 Home](http://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i).