# NTFS long path policy doesn't work on new windows update

Tags: windows-10, ntfs

This morning I updated my windows 10 with

• Feature update to Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1703.

After that my policy that enables long paths stopped working ( I guess? ). I see it as enabled but when I try to compile some stuff that have long path tree my compile fails.

When I pull the files out from the long tree closer to the root it works.

I reverted my windows update to the previous version and now everything works as usual.

Comment: It absolutely does work.  If it's not working then it's the applications fault.  You are going to have to trust I know more about this feature

Comment: Programming Solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1114572/windows-10-ver-1607-file-explorer-long-paths-not-working your inability to compile the program has nothing to do with enabling the feature on your client machine.  Your inability to compile your program is a different out of scope problem

Comment: @Rahmound I wouldn't say it's a duplicate since I solved my initial problem with the thread that you've linked. After todays new windows update it stopped working.

Also my inability to run my grunt task is related to this. Why? For the reasons I explain in this thread. I pulled my folders outside of the long tree path and I was able to run my grunt tasks. I concluded that the long path tree is causing problems. The same problems that happend before I enabled long path policy.

And when I reverted windows update it suddenly works again.

Comment: Well I can personally confirm this feature still works in 1703.  The location of the policy changed between I believe it was 1607 and 1711 to a more permanent location