# Windows 10 limits the file names

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs

Windows 10 is killing me. I want to write some file names with more than 80 characters. I have a folder path like that: `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Formations\Maitriser les outils vectoriels d Illustrator et de Photoshop\Illustrator CC - L art des courbes vectorielles\02 - Demarrer cette formation sur Illustrator CC`. When I create a file into that folder and start typing the file name Windows only let me type only 50 characters. For example: `Nouveau document texte jhkds fjkdshfkj sfhjsdh.txt`. When I get into `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Formations\Maitriser les outils vectoriels d Illustrator et de Photoshop\Illustrator CC - L art des courbes vectorielles` it let me write at maximum 99 characters like `Nouveau document texte khfjddjg djfhjdshf jdshf sdfsjdfjsd fds fsd fjsdfjdsjfhsdjfh djsfhjsdhfj.txt`. When I get into `C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Formations\Maitriser les outils vectoriels d Illustrator et de Photoshop` it allows me to write a file name with maximum 147 characters like `Nouveau document texte djkshfkjs djfk hfjdshjf jshfjhsd fjshfjs dhfjhs djfhsjdhf jsdhfjhsdj fhds fhsdj fjdshfj hsdjhf sdhfjh sdjhf shdjf sjdhf .txt`. each time I get closer to `c:\` it increases the filename maximum length.

I even create a Python script to try to create a filename longer than the maximum allowed by Windows, Python throws an exception like `File or directory not found` (something like that).

I have `LongPathsEnabled` set to `1` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem`.

My Hard drive is `GPT` and `NTFS`, it has 2 `NTFS` partitions.

What is wrong with Windows? How to fix it?

Comment: Your file path contains more than 260 characters. [It also might be the script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365797/python-long-filename-support-broken-in-windows). If it’s the script that would be a question for Stack Overflow not Super User. [Looks like long path support in Python is tricky.](https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/997)

Comment: @Ramhound It's not about script but About the Windows OS. I just mentioned Python to make understand that Windows does not allow Long file name even if I enabled `Long paths support`.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1114683/766217https://superuser.com/a/1114683/766217). It indicates that even if the `LongPathsEnable` entry is in place, Windows Explorer is still limited. And as Ramhound points out, Python is also tricky. Just because it is enabled in the registry, it doesn't mean that every application can handle long paths. Try a third-party file management tool.

Comment: @user3502626 - Then you are out of luck.  You need to have a path with less than 260 characters.

Comment: The key `LongPathsEnabled` only works when the application [includes the longPathAware element in its manifest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). It's not a global flag. And Explorer still doesn't have good long file name support so you'll have to work with command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Explorer does not support long paths and does not correctly handle the
`LongPathsEnabled` registry entry.

You may file a bug report with Microsoft using the Feedback Hub, but I assume that
many others have already done that before you, but with no effect.

Your only options as I see them are:

- Shorten the folder name using the
  [subst command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst)
  to give a phony drive-letter to part of the path.
  For example:

  ```
  subst z: "C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Formations\Maitriser les outils vectoriels d Illustrator et de Photoshop\Illustrator CC - L art des courbes vectorielles"
  ```
- Use a third-party file-manager, other than Explorer. For a large choice,
  see the article:
  [Best Free File Manager](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm).
  I also add here
  [Altap Salamander 4.0 Freeware](https://www.altap.cz/).