# STILL no file paths longer than 260 characters in Win Explorer, in 2023?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, path, characters

When I try to create a subfolder in a folder whose file path is already cca 260 characters, I get this message:

> **The file name(s) would be too long for the destination folder. You can shorten the file name and try again, or try a location that has a shorter path.**

I also have the issue with Windows Explorer crashing when I try to open a location that exceeds 260 characters in the path, which often happens for example while using Google Drive for Windows.

So, I googled the issue and found some tips.

I have tried the following:

- Edited the registry: set the ***LongPathsEnabled*** parameter of REG_DWORD in the registry key *HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ControlFileSystem* with a **value 1**.
- In the **Local Group Policy Editor** - in
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System >
  Filesystem*, I have set the policy parameter named **Enable Win32 long paths**
  to *Enabled*.

It made no difference.

I have googled further and searched this site, and I found many topics with identical advice to what I already did above, and also [some discouraging info](https://superuser.com/questions/1476969/windows-10-limits-the-file-names/1477277#1477277) saying that Windows Explorer "does not YET support long file in its manifest, and we have to wait for them to implement it". However, all these answers are many years old.

It is now 2023. I can't find any recent discussions on this issue.

So I am wondering if it is just me or IS IT POSSIBLE?? That we STILL can't have *native* Windows Explorer support for paths over 260 chars, in 2023?

I am running:

- 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor.
- Windows 10 Pro
- Version  21H2
- OS build 19044.2846
- Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0

Comment: It depends on the **file system (FS)** being able to handle long paths, as well as the operating system. NTFS can do so, but not many other FS. See https://doc.owncloud.com/server/next/admin_manual/troubleshooting/path_filename_length.html

Comment: ^ Filesystem limitations aren't the issue here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So I am wondering if it is just me or IS IT POSSIBLE?? That we STILL can't have native Windows Explorer support for paths over 260 chars, in 2023?

The answer to your question is: **Unfortunately no.**

It depends on Microsoft to add it, and so far they have not done so. The `LongPathsEnabled` registry and the `Enable Win32 long paths` Group Policy (which do the same thing) enables it on the system (the *Win32 API*), but Windows Explorer does not support it.

(And given that they're planning to change the File Explorer in Windows 11 to a new one which is a complete remake, I highly doubt any changes are coming to the legacy one.)

Your only option would be to use an alternative File Explorer that supports Long Paths. Examples are [**OneCommander**](https://onecommander.com/index.php), [**Total Commander**](https://www.ghisler.com/index.htm), and [**7-Zip**](https://7-zip.org/). (A nicer option that seems to support it, and can act as a Windows Explorer replacement with a similar layout, but isn't free, is the [**Files App**](https://files.community/).)

Comment: Well, that .. is an utter disgrace. But thank you, for clarifying. 
Roll on, win11... :(

Comment: I recommend using [Directory Opus](https://www.gpsoft.com.au/). I have successfully tested it to create, edit, and navigate enormously long paths. I did not have success with the Files app.

Comment: Windows 11 or Windows Server 2022 still does not support long file paths in the File Explorer by the way, the long file path registry setting is meant for 3rd party applications to hook into, they actually have to declare their support for it in the app manifest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry Microsoft haven't updated Explorer to support it due to compatibility concerns.

Comment: "they actually have to declare their support for it in the app manifest" -- that's no big deal, and simply indicates that the app is aware that it may encounter long paths. "Microsoft haven't updated Explorer to support it due to compatibility concerns" -- if that's their reasoning then its foolish--it's more incompatible for WE to not support files that other apps readily create.

Comment: Directory Opus worked for me too! Big thanks to the developers. Crazy that Windows still struggles with this in 2023