# Why is the registry edit permitting long path links in Windows not working?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have attempted to enable paths longer than 260 characters to be used by following the directions in this help document: [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation). However, despite that change (and restarting my system), I'm still seeing this error:

[image: Error message along with registry entry]

Can someone tell me what is wrong here?

I should note that I found this post ([link](https://superuser.com/questions/1114572/windows-10-ver-1607-file-explorer-long-paths-not-working)) where someone appears to have had a similar issue with the solution being using 3rd-party software, but that was almost 6 years ago, and I'm using Windows 11. Certainly, they've enabled the feature in Explorer by now, right?

Comment: The simple answer: What you want requires specific support and the registry editor doesn’t support it. The answer to the existing question applies to Windows 10.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Maybe my screenshot wasn't clear. The intention was to show that the registry has been properly edited as the help document specifies, yet when I attempt to change the name of a folder (or some similar task), it gives me errors saying the file name(s) would be too long or some such thing.

Comment: FIle Explorer still does not support the long paths.  Originally I mistakenly read the title of your question differently.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the reply. That is shocking.

Comment: The problem for file explorer is VERY complicated because of the way that explorer parses paths using [PIDLs](https://flylib.com/books/en/1.107.1.77/1/) which are arrays of the pieces that make up a path.  Every 3rd party extension (and there are LOTs) would no longer function.  They would need to redesign the explorer completely to support "two ways" of doing things which would create more bloat (and risk) in an already bloated thing.  Also, 'c/c++' programmers that know [COM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal) are hard to come by.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks.