# Why can't I mkdir \\?\%temp%\very\long\path in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, ntfs, path

I found out from several places in the internet that I can use `\\?\` to use the long path feature of NTFS. However, if I try to create a long path in cmd.exe with `mkdir \\?\%TEMP%\a\very\long\path\follows`, I get a `The full path of ... is too long` error.

What am I missing and how can I create a long path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 Home Anniversary update: long path fix not working?](https://superuser.com/questions/1114359/windows-10-home-anniversary-update-long-path-fix-not-working)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the proposed *has already an answer* doesn't even mention \\?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\?\` is an [extended path-length prefix](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) that when passes to the Win32 API will make it ignore the `MAX_PATH` limit. It's not an NTFS feature. However it seems the `mkdir` command parses that string before passing to the *create directory* function, and that's the limitation of the command, not the OS

> **Key:** The path can consist of any valid characters up to the maximum path length.
>
> https://ss64.com/nt/md.html

In Windows 10 you can opt-in to remove the path limit, but on Windows 7 you have only one solution: find a program that supports long path name. One of those is the built-in [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) which supports long path by default and you can turn that off with the option `/256`. You can use the `/E` or `/CREATE` option to create the folder structure by copying from a dummy file/folder. For example

```
C:\>robocopy /create C:\dummy C:\long\path\0123456789\1123456789\223456789\3123456789\4123456789\5123456789\6123456789\7123456789\8123456789\9123456789\0123456789\1123456789\2123456789\3123456789\4123456789\5123456789\6123456789\7123456789\8123456789\9123456789\0123456789\1123456789\2123456789\3123456789\4123456789\5123456789\6123456789\7123456789\8123456789\9123456789\

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ... <skipping many lines>

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /CREATE /R:1000000 /W:30
```

After that you can check the created folders with `ls -R C:\long` in PowerShell

[7-zip also supports long file names](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/b3117cf0/). You can browse the folder structure with it and press <kbd>F7</kbd> to create a new folder. Same to WinRar and Far Manager. Unfortunately they don't seem to have a command line option to create folders

AFAIK Far Manager supports long paths, too. It even [supports scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Manager#Extensibility) so you can write a simple script to do that. Alternatively you can call [`CreateDirectoryW()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createdirectoryw) API directly from PowerShell to create the folder, no 3<sup>rd</sup> component is needed

```powershell
$Signature  = @'[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true,
                CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, BestFitMapping = false)]
    public static extern bool CreateDirectory([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string path,
                                              IntPtr securityAttributes);
'@
$Kernel32 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name 'Kernel32' `
                     -Namespace 'Win32' -PassThru

$pathToCreate = "long\path" + "\0123456789" * 30
$path = "\\?\C:" # or up until the folder you know that already existed
foreach ($p in $pathToCreate.Split('\')) {
    $path += '\' + $p
    $result = $Kernel32::CreateDirectory($path, [System.IntPtr]::Zero)
}
if ($result) { echo "Path created successfully" }
```

But even then you'll face problems if you want to access the folder from Windows Explorer

### Related:

- [How to create directories in windows with path length greater than 256](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6996711/995714)
- [How to create directory exceeding MAX_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17747606/995714)